# React admin. How to filter data from useQueryWithStore Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I need to create a page that contains `<Datagrid />` with data from `customers_activity` resource with logic of `getManyReference` (according to `customer_id` from `customers` resource).

I cannot just use `<List />` component because it uses `/get_list` method, but I need to load data according to that `customer_id`, that is why here will fit `/getManyReference`.

I was thinking of just adding this data as `<ReferenceManyField />` in a tab view of customers component, but I need it to be different page and also with `<Filters />` as on List component.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you create a custom button in customer list which redirect to customers_activity resources with a customer filter ?

ex: http://localhost:3000/#/customer_activity?filter="customer_id"

Comment: @Fabzien then if someone goes to that link and remove filter parameters I would need to show activity for all the users or error, that is not ok. The idea is that I have page with one user activity per time